# testing the significance of paramateres based on z test of coefficients R output

Tags: r, statistical-significance

[image]

based on the r output below, what is my significance value (p-value) for AR1, and is AR1 a significant parameter? if significant, why?

Answer (score 0):

the p-value you obtained is very small ~2.27e-5, that means we reject the null hypothesis, and we can conclude that the ar1 coefficient is significant for this model.

this answer is based on the table you provided, and I am assuming that the modelling that led you to that table is correct.